# Azure ADO Build Pipeline failed due to brown out of ubuntu 16.04

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

My pipelines refer to ubuntu-latest pool, but I'm getting this error about Ubuntu 16.04

The docs state that ubuntu-latest is an alias for ubuntu-20.04
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software

EDIT: I changed to ubuntu-20.04 and still getting the brownout and my job canceled

Azure DevOps Pipelines is effectively down right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the default agent pool being set to an outdated version of ubuntu

Edit the build

From the menu select triggers

Select the YAML tab

[image]

Update to a valid option

I also recommend update / setting the pool on every job so that it will not use the default (making it more clear and easy to fix)